# Where did the nickname of 'Bones' for McCoy come from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I've noticed that Jim Kirk often refers to Dr McCoy affectionately as 'Bones'.  Now, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bones) gives the following explanation:

> Bones is short for "Saw Bones" ...
>   The use of "Bones" originates with the term "sawbones" in 19th century
>   American medicine where military doctors, especially surgeons, were
>   called "saw bones" because of all the amputations they had to perform
>   during the Civil War.

Yet, there is no citation for this.  My question is, **what is the in-universe origin of this name?  i.e. why was McCoy associated with a 19th century doctor?**  I am looking for information from *TOS*, **not** the Abramsverse.

Comment: Fun fact, in the German translation he is called "Pille" which means pill. I guess this is due to the fact that the translation for bone, "Knochen", would irritate German viewers.

Comment: @user14111: just because Dickens is the first written source we have doesn’t mean that the term wasn’t popular, or popularised, in America during the Civil War.

Comment: @user14111: maybe it became popular in America during the American Civil War.

Comment: Related trivia: [Dr. Boyce](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Philip_Boyce) (from *The Cage*) had the same nickname.

Comment: @Thomas: Indeed! Nicknaming someone "Knochen", my first association would be that the person was meant to be dull, sluggish, unresponsive.

Comment: I would assume it is associated with past war(s) because it sounds like basic medicine - no slight on the military intended there, you know what I mean. I certainly wouldn't want to be worked on by a 'saw bones' if I was injured now!

Comment: "why was McCoy associated with a 19th century doctor?" um, because he's a doctor?

Comment: @OrangeDog that's like saying it's appropriate to call a pharmacist today an alchemist!  From the perspective of *TOS*, it was set in the **22nd century**, quite a while away from the 19th century

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I noticed that as well, and it solidifies my suspicion that there's no satisfying in-universe reason for the nickname; it's just something Roddenberry wanted to be, so it is.

Comment: One of the bits to consider out of universe is that Star Trek TOS was on television in the heyday of the western television series. The audience would understand the linkage between 'Bones', 'sawbones' and doctor.

Comment: @Thomas: Interesting! In English, to call a person a "pill" is to say that he is very annoying (just as a pill is unpleasant to swallow).

Comment: @O. R. Mapper interesting; in English Bone Idle is similar; i.e. meaning lazy / slobbish.

Comment: @N_Soong: (*23rd* century, not 22nd.) True, but we know that the TOS Kirk was *really* into his history, and we know he was at least somewhat familiar with the American West from *The Spectre of the Gun*, so it's an unsurprising thing for Kirk to know even if most 23rd century people wouldn't.

Comment: When slang, or a neologisms enter a language, they may stay or go. "Mugwump" (someone who can't make up their mind) is 19th century slang we rarely see now, but I heard with some frequency in the 60's.  The "in universe citation" requirement ignores how TV script writing was done in the 60's in the US: in English, and in recognizable idiom, and not quite a obsessively as for 21st century geek culture.  Question down voted: the script used recognizable slang. The answer is in the question's citation. Demanding "in universe" citation for a 60's originated script artifact is bad retcon.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I agree that they may not have had an in-universe explanation in mind for the nickname when they introduced it.  It's still an interesting question to ask if one was ever shown later, and how much of a stretch it is.

Comment: Sorry for probably hijacking this post, but is this also the case in [Dr. Temperance 'Bones' Brennan](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0027448/)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Kirk calls McCoy "*Saw**bones***" in [TOS: A Piece of the Action](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/49.htm).

I would hypothesise that "*bones*" is a contraction of "sawbones".

> **MCCOY:** *Jim.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Knock it off, Sawbones. I want to talk to this creep. Now listen, I'm getting tired of playing pattycake with you penny-ante
>   operators.*

Comment: I didn't think to look for the longer term *in* the episodes themselves.  +1

Comment: Great find!  Richard strikes again ;)

Comment: That's episode 49. According to the transcripts on www.chakoteya.net, Kirk called McCoy "Bones" as early as episode 5 (aired 15 months earlier), and in the majority of episodes after that.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why Kirk talks like a  Cagney-esque prohibition-era gangster in this scene, this is one of those "We went to an alien planet which was weirdly like an era out of Earth's history" episodes.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - to be fair, this episode was based on the fact that a previous mission had left a book on gangsters (for some bizzaro-world reason) - their world didn't accidently end up that way. Unlike Bread and Circuses which is "just a coincidence."

Comment: @HannoverFist aha, that still doesn't make sense but at least there's a backstory, thanks :)

Answer (score 35):

When interviewed regarding his *Autobiography of James T. Kirk*, *Star Trek: Enterprise* writer David A. Goodman stated his belief that "Bones" came from "sawbones":

> The other thing that I’m very proud of is how Kirk came up with the name Bones. It’s not how it is in J.J [Abrams]’ movie, **because in my mind Bones was a shortening of Sawbones, which is an Old West name for a doctor**. I wanted something to happen in these guys' experience where Kirk would coin that nickname, and I’m very happy with that as well, in what I came up with.

([Source](http://www.hypable.com/david-goodman-interview/2/))

Comment: I think the ancient history of the nickname reminds us that a lot has changed over the centuries but we're still from Earth, dammit. Which is true i think for pretty much his whole character!

Comment: @Richard : I just replaced the answer entirely.  This fellow has some connection to Star Trek (has written for *Enterprise*) and did a lot of background research for his book about Kirk.

Comment: Downvote removed. A much better quote although I'd far rather see something from someone involved in the original series.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm chasing up a lead: apparently there is a book called *Star Trek Memories* where Roddenberry mentions the "sawbones" -> "Bones" contraction.  But I don't have it.

Comment: This is a good answer, but might be improved with quotes from the book itself, or a summary of what happened that got Kirk to coin that nickname.

Comment: Just a side note that in the JJ Abrams alternate timeline, they explain this soon after Kirk and McCoy have met on a shuttle heading for orbit, with McCoy saying that he's joining Starfleet because he has nowhere else to go: *"[The ex wife took the whole damned planet in the divorce. All I've got left is my bones.](https://youtu.be/RlphfLO3MYA?t=43s)"* Personally, I didn't like it (and Abrams says it was an ad lib by Karl Urban they decided to keep), since the sawbones theory makes such good sense.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude : The problem with the early 21st Century is that most books are still pay-walled...

Comment: "*The ex wife took the whole damned planet in the divorce. All I've got left is my bones.*" In the novelization of the movie, the line was inexplicably changed to use the word "skeleton" rather than "bones". If the "bones" line was an ad lib, perhaps the novelization was based on an earlier version of the script?

Answer (score 14):

TOS is a document of American culture in the mid 20th century. There are many period cultural references scattered all over that series.

Calling a doctor "Bones" is actually a US military cultural reference, a combat surgeon. While it originated from the "Sawbones" of the civil war, it was also in common use during the writing of TOS.

There are many other references to US military culture in TOS, and Star Fleet had to be at least loosely modeled on what the author was familiar with.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am looking specifically for *why* McCoy in particular was called by Jim 'Bones'; I don't recall anyone else calling him Bones...

Answer (score 6):

Kirk called Dr. McCoy "Bones" because Gene Rodenberry pitched "Star Trek" as "Wagon Train" to the stars, and gave the Dr. character the nickname “Bones” from the beginning.  As previous answers have noted, “Bones” was  a common nickname for a doctor in our culture at least since the Civil War, and would have been used in radio shows,  movies,  and TV shows, so easily understood and accepted by a general audience in the ‘60s.

This is specifically stated in Rodenberry’s  original Series Format: "THE FORMAT is "Wagon Train to the Stars."   Later in that document, in describing the U.S.S. Enterprise: "As with "Gunsmoke" 's Dodge City, "Kildare" 's Blair General Hospital, our Cruiser is a complete and highly varied community; . . ."

And finally, "*Ship's Doctor*. Philip Boyce, M.D. is a highly unlikely space traveler. . . . Captain April's only real confidant, "Bones" Boyce considers himself the only realist aboard . . . ."

Source:  “The Making of Star Trek,” Stephen E. Whitfield, Gene Rodenberry, 1968, Ballantine Books,  New York.  It has been reissued many times.   I bought my copy in 1973, and highly recommend it.   It was written real-time, so is not distorted by people’s selective memories.  And it’s hilarious.  The Vulcan names memos still make me laugh out loud.

It’s been a while since I read it cover to cover, but I don’t recall any reason(s) ever being given in the backstory for Kirk to call McCoy “Bones.”

Answer (score 0):

While it is pretty clear from the above answers that the author originally derived the name "Bones" from "Sawbones", the 2009 Star Trek movie suggests a different origin.

When Kirk and Bones first meet on the shuttle leaving earth, McCoy remarks that "My wife took the entire planet in the divorce. All I got left is my bones."

The movie can get away with that, since it is prequel to TOS. It does not necessarily change the meaning of the name, but gives additional detail about how the name came to him.

Comment: [Gosh, this sounds familiar](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/where-did-the-nickname-of-bones-for-mccoy-come-from#comment229463_99676) ;-)

Comment: *"The movie can get away with that, since it is prequel to TOS"* No, it's an alternate timeline.

Comment: The OP specifically said that he does not want information regarding the 2009 film, just *The Original Series*.

Comment: ***not** the Abramsverse.* the OP requests. I get the idea he knows the line from that movie already.

Comment: Yes, as I do explain explicitly in the question, I'm not interested in the explanation in the Abramsverse!

Answer (score -1):

Saw Bones was a common nick name for field doctors, and this is where the nickname comes from, as others have said. Also in the recon'd version of Star Trek form the films "Bones" was a nickname given from his first interaction with Kirk on a transport ship heading to Star Fleet Academy. "I lost everything in the divorce, all I've got left is my Bones." Is the quite I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did state in my question that I wasn't interested in the Abramsverse version.

Comment: The OP (@N_Soong) explained the meaning of "sawbones" in the question.  The OP was seeking an origin for "bones" *with a citation*.  Also, he explicitly excluded the 2009 film.

Comment: Interesting trivia anyway: In the German version of the 2009 film, McCoy say "Das war eine bittere Pille" (That was a bitter pill) to make the text match the German nickname Pille for McCoy (cf. Thomas comment to the OP)

Answer (score -1):

Kirk is a history buff..McCoy and Kirk go back many years.I recall Lenord giving Jim beautiful leather bound books for his BDay or XMass.Of course Kirk knows the origin and use of "Sawbones" because of his interest in early century publishing and history.Bones is a term of affection coming from Kirk-because McCoy knows Jim so well and his love of books.

Comment: History buff...Oh, you mean Picard. He hath quoteth such great works from Shakespeare.